# Security of three-pass mutual authentication under ISO/IEC 9798-2

Tags: authentication

Based on 5.2.2 of the international standard ISO/IEC 9798-2 (http://bcc.portal.gov.bd/sites/default/files/files/bcc.portal.gov.bd/page/adeaf3e5_cc55_4222_8767_f26bcaec3f70/ISO_IEC_9798-2.pdf)

Why does the protocol swap the 2 nonces in TokenBA (Rb||Ra, instead of directly taking Ra||Rb in TokenAB) ? If we do use Rb||Ra, and assume the size of blocks in the messages are equal to the block size of the block cipher used to perform the encryption, will the protocol still be secure when the CBC mode is used ? How about counter mode?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, appreciate if you can shed some lights